# Why is the installation of the SingleCellExperiment package taking significantly longer on my Anaconda environment compared to my colleague's?

Tags: r, package, anaconda, conda

My colleague and I are using the same server for our analysis, each with our own accounts. We utilized the same .sh file to install Anaconda, and then executed exactly the same commands to create an conda environment with R version 4.1.3. Afterward, we used the exact same command to install the SingleCellExperiment package. Surprisingly, my colleague was able to install it in just 5 minutes using the 'conda' command without any issues, whereas my installation took a staggering 1 hour before I had to abort it. Here are the commands we used:

```
conda create --name r4-base 
conda activate r4-base 
conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.3 r-essentials 
conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-singlecellexperiment
```

What factors could potentially cause such a significant difference in installation times on the same server with nearly identical configurations?

In another effort, I tried to install mamba, it got pretty fast but there are a lot of errors and dependency issues and errors. While installing mamba on his account and trying the command with that, we could install it without any issue.

A note here, my colleague has his installation from long time ago and we just tried to create a new environment. However, mine is fresh installation of everything.

any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see how anyone can answer this with any specificity. Insufficiently documented for a high quality answer.

Comment: @IRTFM can you guide me what should I include?

Comment: I would think that knowing what hardware and software were being used as a start. The description of hardware would include processor speed and available RAM and state of the external storage (SSD or HDD). The description of the software would need to include OS, how much of the RAM is occupied by other programs, versions of R, versions of anaconda, explanation why an out-of-date version of R is being installed, locations of repositories, description of the network characteristics ... And that's probably an incomplete list.

Comment: I think it's possibly more appropriate for the SuperUser forum since has has zero probability of having anything to do with coding in a programming language.

Comment: Note that `conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-singlecellexperiment` is not a correct specification. *Bioconda must have Conda Forge prioritized*, and even worse, but not specifying `conda-forg` at all, Conda could be trying to use **defaults** channels to satisfy dependencies. Highly likely that's what makes it slow. Point being, Bioconda packages must use: `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda bioconductor-singlecellexperiment`. Also, consider using YAMLs that you version control to define environments - *ad hoc* install commands do not yield reproducible environments.

Comment: @IRTFM while it could be many things as you say, it's most likely due to not using the Bioconda channel properly. This comes up frequently in the `conda` tag.